# Why do I get different values if I access a globally-declared array elements using a user-defined function and main() function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I've written this C code in which the `int* arrayInit();` assigns values to a globally declared array of 3 elements and returns the address of the first element of the array.In Segment 1, the array elements and their respective addresses are printed using the fuction `int* arrayInit()` and the same elements and addresses are printed in Segment 2 using the function `void main()`. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int array[3];   //global declaration of array

int *arrayInit()
   {
    int array[]={1,2,3};
    int* ptr=&array[0];

    /*Segment 1:
      To print the array elements and its address using
      user-defined function*/
    printf("\nSegment 1 : Through User-Defined Function:");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        printf("\n%d\t%p",array[i],&array[i]);

    return ptr;
   }

void main()
   {
    int *pointer=arrayInit();        //storing address returned by arrayInit()

    /*Segment 2:
      To print the array elements and its address using
      user-defined function*/ 
    printf("\n\nSegment 2 : Through Main Function:");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)     //will perform the operation 3 times
         {
          printf("\n%d\t%p",*pointer,pointer);
          pointer++;
         }
   }
```

When I run this code, I get a result somewhat like this:

```
Segment 1 : Through User-Defined Function:
1       0061FEDC
2       0061FEE0
3       0061FEE4

Segment 2 : Through Main Function:
24      0061FEDC
6422220 0061FEE0
3       0061FEE4
```

The strange thing is that the addresses in both Segment 1 and Segment 2 are same but the values in those addresses are different when accessed through different functions. Please explain.

Thank You.

Comment: You have **two** arrays.Just use different names for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `arrayInit` function doesn't access the global `array` at all. It has its own local `array` that *hides* the global.

It then returns a pointer to that *local* array - so main gets a pointer to that local. But that array ceases to exist as soon as the `arrayInit` function has returned. So reading from that pointer in main is undefined behavior.

Either:

- initialize the array at global scope (and don't use the `arrayInit` function at all)
- initialize the array in `initArray`: don't have a local with the same name in there, just fill in the global one
- dynamically allocate the array in `initArray` (with `malloc`). In this case, `main` becomes responsible for `free`ing it.

Example for the second point:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[3];

void arrayInit() {
  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    array[i] = i+1;
  }
}

int main() {
  arrayInit();

  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    printf("%d\t%p\n", array[i], &array[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: @HarshKhare: added an example for the second option.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int array[]={1,2,3};
> ```

All the problems lie in this statement. Actually, the `Array` that you declared in global space is not at all accessed. Since, you declared `array` again in local space of `arrayInit` function, it has it's own array. Either add extern declaration or `malloc` it.

In some compiles, like mine (GCC 6.3) you may get the desired output because the program is short and no variable access the allocated `Initialized Data Segment`. But there is a hazard of that data being overwritten because as soon as the value from the `arrayInit` is returned, the memory associated with local `array` is freed and is accessible to other variables.

The correct version is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int array[3];   //global declaration of array

int *arrayInit()
   {
    extern int array[3];
    array[0]=1;
    array[1]=2;
    array[2]=3;
    int* ptr=&array[0];

    printf("\nSegment 1 : Through User-Defined Function:");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        printf("\n%d\t%p",array[i],&array[i]);

    return ptr;
   }

void main()
   {
    int *pointer=arrayInit();        

    printf("\n\nSegment 2 : Through Main Function:");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)     //will perform the operation 3 times
         {
          printf("\n%d\t%p",*pointer,pointer);
          pointer++;
         }
   }
```